# How to find this input box?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this input box and I need to fill it with text but the problem this input box has no name or id also the class used is exactly the same like another input box in the same page so how I can select this input box so I can use `SendKeys()`

Here is the HTML:

```
<input tabindex="2" required="" type="password" ng-change="vm.loginForm.pass.$setDirty()" ng-focus="vm.loginForm.pass.$focus = true" ng-blur="vm.loginForm.pass.$focus = false" placeholder="Password" ng-model="vm.password" class="common-input ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" stl="pass_input">
```

I use C#

Comment: If selector in my answer still match both input fields, show `HTML` for second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find it using `XPath` as below:

```
var inputField = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='password']");
inputField.SendKeys("yourPass");
```